# My blogger site throwing some errors in Validator of W3?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, blogger

I have a website on blogger.com *(mywebsite.blogspot.com)*

When I run validation for my site at https://validator.w3.org. it shows me Errors like this -

**Attribute xmlns:b not allowed here.**
[image]

Here is my HTML Code Demo-

```
<html class='v2' dir='ltr' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://yourjavascript.com/69231961363/jquery-colorbox-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I have been wondering for a long time how I can solve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

1- add the lang="es" in to

2- The xmlns attribute specifies the xml namespace for a document. Note: The xmlns attribute is required in XHTML, invalid in HTML 4.01, and optional in HTML5. Note: The HTML validator at http://w3.org does not complain when the xmlns attribute is missing in an XHTML document.

i hope solve the problem.